# Remove (Clone) name from gameobject spawned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game which spawns several objects but with the name (Clone) next to it, however I want to remove (Clone). Excuse me, I am new to Unity, and have tried several solutions but never worked.

I can send script file of instantiating objects if needed.

```
public void InstantiateObject()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            Instantiate(target, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
            target.name = target.name.Replace("(Clone)","").Trim();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `target` is a GameObject, you can declare a variable during instantiation, then change the instantiated object's name like so:

```cs
GameObject newTarget = Instantiate(target, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
newTarget.name = newTarget.name.Replace("(Clone)","").Trim();
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it wasn't working. I just restarted Unity and it worked somehow. Anyways, I am thankful for you and sorry for wasting time. @Chris McFarland